# Synchronizing Desktop App Converter app settings across devices

Tags: winapi, uwp, desktop-app-converter

[Roaming settings options FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/devices/enterprise-state-roaming-faqs#what-are-the-roaming-settings-options-for-existing-windows-desktop-applications-) in Microsoft documentation says:

> The Desktop Bridge helps you bring your existing Windows desktop apps to the Universal Windows Platform. **From here, minimal code changes will be required to take advantage of Azure AD app data roaming.** The Desktop Bridge provides your apps with an app identity, which is needed to enable app data roaming for existing desktop apps.

But there's no mention of what the *"minimal code changes"* are.

Should the app make use of [`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings)? I use C++ Win32. Do I need to load .NET framework to use the API? Or is there Win32 alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the app make use of Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings API? I use C++ Win32. Do I need to load .NET framework to use the API? Or is there Win32 alternative?

First, I want to let you know that not all UWP APIs are available for the general desktop app. Please check the [UWP APIs available to a packaged desktop app (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api) and [UWP APIs callable from a classic desktop app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt695951(v=vs.85).aspx)

Then, please see [Enhance your desktop application for Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) for more details.

In addition:

> Some Windows 10 experiences (For example: a touch-enabled UI page) must run inside of a modern app container . If you want to add these experiences, extend your desktop application with UWP projects and Windows Runtime Components.

Please also check [Extend your desktop application with modern UWP components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extend) document for more reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though it does not answer the primary question: *"Should the app make use of Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings API?"* - The answer looks like it implies, that the answer is "yes". But can you confirm that, please?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for your reply. The [UWP APIs callable from a classic desktop app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt695951(v=vs.85).aspx) document has explained clearly. `If the DualApiPartition attribute is listed,If the API does need the calling app to have a package identity then the API is not allowed to be called from a classic desktop app. But the API can be called from a classic desktop app that has been converted to a UWP app. Windows.Storage.ApplicationData is an example`